# Finding user input in JSON file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, oop

So I Have two JSON files like this:
FlightEntity

```
[
  {
    "flightId": 0,
    "flightNumber": 6211,
    "departureAirportIATACode": "ANC",
    "arrivalAirportIATACode": "GDN",
    "departureDate": "2015-06-16T03:20:34 -02:00"
  },
  {
    "flightId": 1,
    "flightNumber": 8293,
    "departureAirportIATACode": "LAX",
    "arrivalAirportIATACode": "MIT",
    "departureDate": "2018-03-02T05:12:28 -01:00"
  },
  .
  .
  .
  {
    "flightId": 4,
    "flightNumber": 1551,
    "departureAirportIATACode": "SEA",
    "arrivalAirportIATACode": "LEW",
    "departureDate": "2018-01-11T10:48:16 -01:00"
  }
]
```

Cargo Enity

```
[
  {
    "flightId": 0,
    "baggage": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "weight": 494,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 32
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "weight": 572,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 951
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "weight": 520,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 119
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "weight": 993,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 672
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "weight": 318,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 245
      }
    ],
    "cargo": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "weight": 885,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 893
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "weight": 804,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 407
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "weight": 388,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 674
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I want to get Cargo Weight for requested Flight. For example:

1. User Inputs flight number 6211.
2. I compare the input and take the right flightId from FlightEntity JSON file(in this example it's 0).
3. Then I find the corresponding flightId in Cargo Entity JSON file.
4. Print out the sum of cargo weight. 
   My problem is that I don't know how to find the input value(flight number) in the JSON array and then return corresponding flightId. Right now my code only takes input from user and print whole JSON file from Flight Entity.

```
package com.company;// Java program to read JSON from a file
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println("Enter Flight Number:");

        int FlightNumber = myObj.nextInt() ;  // Read user input
        Scanner newObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Flight Date(yyyy-mm-dd):");
        String Date = newObj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Flight Number: " + FlightNumber);// Output user input
        System.out.println("Flight Number: " + Date);// Output user input
        Flight(FlightNumber, Date);
    }
    public static void Flight(int number, String date) throws IOException, ParseException {
        // parsing file "CargoEntity.json"
        Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("FlightEntity.json"));

        // typecasting obj to JSONObject
        JSONArray jo=(JSONArray)obj;

        // getting Flight id for our number
        //Iterating the contents of the array
        for (Object o : jo) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to receive some feedback you must show the code that you have tried until how. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get to the `flightNumber` and `flightId` by modifying your `Flight` function as follows:

```
for (Object o : jo) {
    JSONObject flight = (JSONObject)o;
    Long flightNumber = (Long)flight.get("flightNumber");
    Long flightId = (Long)flight.get("flightId");
    if (flightNumber.intValue() == number) {
        System.out.println("corresponding flightId is: " + flightId);
    }
}
```

Individual flight `o` is cast as `JSONObject` which allows accessing corresponding attributes via the `get` method.